# Responsive error on 2436 x 1125 screen resolution(landscape mode)

Tags: iphone, wordpress, css, iphone-x

Here is my website's responsive version on [different devices and resolutions](http://www.responsinator.com/?url=x-architecture.co.uk%2F) Please, pay attention to the menu icon on landscape mode.

I have [this problem with Menu icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tAfF.jpg) on iPhone X landscape mode.

I use this code and it's work with any other devices and resolutions(landscape):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 710px) {
    .mobile-mini-widgets {
       display: none!important;
    }
}
```

But it's not work with iphone X.
I even tried this code for iphone X but it doesn't work too:

```
/* iphone X */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-height: 
812px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {
    .mobile-mini-widgets {
        display: none!important;
    }
}
```

Could you please to help to resolve this issue?

Comment: iphoneX max width is greater than 710px https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions

Comment: You want to have this item _displayed_, not _hidden_ for that breakpoint, because this element is what sits between the logo and the menu icon and thereby pushes the menu icon to the right. (Although, if that was the _only_ purpose this empty element serves, then you would better be using flexbox properties properly to align the two actual items.)

Comment: @misorude Thanks for you reply. Well my main aim is to have logo left and menu icon right in any mobile/ipad device, resolution and orientation. How can I get it without his code I use now?

Comment: @Carol McKay Thanks for you reply. So how much pixel I have to set for iphone X? I'm not sure...

Comment: If the only purpose of the `.mobile-mini-widgets` element was to achieve _that_, then remove it - and instead specify how you want to remaining two elements inside your flex container to be laid out - that’s what the `justify-content` property is for.

Comment: If I will remove this code I use, logo will be in the center and I will not be able to get it left.

Comment: Ok, I remove this code I used and now the logo is in the center. How to put in the left corner?

Comment: you may need to specify .mobile-mini-widgets {flex-basis:auto}